# PHP - Return single row from associated arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-filter

Let say I have the datas in JSON,

3 people have different datas such as `New` only / `New and Old` / `Old and New`.

I tried using `isset($_GET['NoID']);` which is

`http://localhost/test.php?NoID=31331 // Stan Lee`

`http://localhost/test.php?NoID=31332 // Mary Jane`

`http://localhost/test.php?NoID=31335 // John Doe`

And the result are:

```js
// Stan Lee 


{
   - Table: [
         - {
             Name: "Stan Lee",
             NoID: "31331",
             Type: "New",
           - @attributes: {
                    id: "Table1",
                    rowOrder: "0",
              }
            },
            
          ]
     }


// Mary Jane 

{
   - Table: [
         - {
             Name: "Mary Jane",
             NoID: "31332",
             Type: "New",
           - @attributes: {
                    id: "Table1",
                    rowOrder: "0",
              }
            },
            
         - {
             Name: "Mary Jane",
             NoID: "31333",
             Type: "Old",
           - @attributes: {
                    id: "Table2",
                    rowOrder: "1",
              }
            },
          ]
     }
     
        
// John Doe

{
   - Table: [
         - {
             Name: "John Doe",
             NoID: "31334",
             Type: "Old",
           - @attributes: {
                    id: "Table1",
                    rowOrder: "0",
              }
            },
            
         - {
             Name: "John Doe",
             NoID: "31335",
             Type: "New",
           - @attributes: {
                    id: "Table2",
                    rowOrder: "1",
              }
            },
          ]
     }
```

I want to return which is condition is `New` only (Single row).

I tried to `foreach()` then strict statement for `New` and `break`, also I tried `array_filter()` and `sort()`. Those function didn't work out to return `New` only.

My code I tried so far:

```js
foreach ($data['Table'] as $value) {
  if (is_array($value) && $value['Type'] == "New") {
   json($value);

      break;
  } elseif (is_string($value)) {
   json($value);

      break;
  }
 }
```

And the output is

```js
Notice: Undefined index: Type
"New"
```

Both `Mary Jane` & `John Doe` gimme the right output, but `Stan Lee` didn't work.

Anyone can help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: Post the codes you've tried. Also, give sample of actual and expected outputs.

Comment: youe question is not clear  ..

Comment: already edited the question. Sorry! :D

Comment: In your `$data` is no key `$data['Table']` !

Comment: Fixed that @ino

Comment: @rootnel what do you want as your output at the last??

Comment: @Sohel0415 i want the output display "New" only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi bro i have checked you code and i just remove the break try this:

```
 $data = ["Table" => [[
            "Name" => "Stan Lee",
            "NoID" => "31331",
            "Type" => "New",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table1",
                 "rowOrder"=> "0"
                   ]
           ],
           [
            "Name" => "Mary Jane",
            "NoID" => "31332",
            "Type" => "New",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table1",
                     "rowOrder" => "0"
                   ]
           ],
           [
            "Name" => "Mary Jane",
            "NoID" => "31333",
            "Type" => "Old",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table2",
                     "rowOrder" =>"1"
                   ]
           ],

            [
            "Name" => "John Doe",
            "NoID" => "31334",
            "Type" => "Old",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table1",
                     "rowOrder"=>"0"
                   ]
           ],

           [
            "Name" => "John Doe",
            "NoID" => "31335",
            "Type" => "New",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table2",
                     "rowOrder" => "1"
                   ]
           ],
 ]

     ];


 foreach ($data['Table'] as $value) {
    if (is_array($value) && $value['Type'] == "New") {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($value);
        echo '</pre>';

    } elseif (is_string($value)) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($value);
        echo '</pre>';

  break;
    }
}
```

and here is the output:

```
Array
 (
    [Name] => Stan Lee
    [NoID] => 31331
    [Type] => New
    [attributes] => Array
     (
         [id] => Table1
         [rowOrder] => 0
     )

 )
 Array
 (
   [Name] => Mary Jane
   [NoID] => 31332
   [Type] => New
   [attributes] => Array
     (
         [id] => Table1
         [rowOrder] => 0
     )

 )
 Array
 (
   [Name] => John Doe
   [NoID] => 31335
   [Type] => New
   [attributes] => Array
      (
         [id] => Table2
         [rowOrder] => 1
     )

  )
```

Let me know if this is what you need. feel free to ask.

Comment: No bro, its your code i just removed the break; in your code. Your welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `break;` from the `foreach()` loop.

`break` will interrupt the loop and no more array keys/values are treated anymore.

[PHP break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

**edit**

Probable you do not want to sent the json each time the condition is met.
So before the foreach() create variable `$output`  and collect matched values to it `$output[] = $value;`. And finally send the whole output using `json($output);`

```
<?php

  $data = [
  "Table" => [
        "Type" => "New"
       ],
       [
         1 => ["Type" => "New"],
         2 => ["Type" => "Old"],
       ],
       [
         1 => ["Type" => "Old"],
         2 => ["Type" => "New"],
       ]
     ];


foreach ($data['Table'] as $key => $value) {
    If($key == 'Type' and $value == 'New'){
      $output[] = $value;
    }
```

Comment: this works for second and third array. But the first one didnt work. It returns 

`Notice: Undefined index: Type
["Type": "New"]`

Comment: After all the edits I missed the first item is also an array. Now the `is_array()` is not needed any more since it seems to be an array always.

Comment: Now I realizedt that all you need is to check the key 'Type' for 'New' value. So the if-elseif is not needed...

Comment: Still the same problem with the first array. 
`Warning: Illegal string offset Type` 
`Notice: Undefined index: Type`



Comment: I edited the question with well json formatted. Sorry so much @ino

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
     $newArray = array();
     foreach($data as $key => $d){
         if(sizeof($d) > 1){
             foreach($d as $key1 => $d1){
                 if(strtolower($d1['Type']) == 'new'){
                     $newArray[$key1]['Type'] = $d1['Type'];
                 }
             }
         }else{
            if(strtolower($d['Type']) == 'new'){
                $newArray[$key]['Type'] = $d['Type'];
            }
         }
     }
     print_r(json_encode($newArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function arraySearch($array,$keyword="type",$value="New",$results=[]) {
        foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
        if(is_array($val)){
            if(array_key_exists($keyword,$val)){
                if ($val[$keyword] === $value ) {
                    $results[] = $key;
                }   
            }else{
                arraySearch($array,$keyword,$value,$results);
            }   
        }
    }
       return json($results);
}
```

Call to function:

```
echo arraySearch($data['Table']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter` like this, [demo](https://eval.in/939719)

```
array_filter($data, function($v){
    return count($v) == 1 && $v['Type'] == 'New'; 
})
```

Comment: It's works, please check the live demo which base on your first version question.

Answer (score 0):

Result: `[{"0":"New","1":"New","4":"New"}]`

```
<?php


 $data = ["Table" => [[
            "Name" => "Stan Lee",
            "NoID" => "31331",
            "Type" => "New",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table1",
                 "rowOrder"=> "0"
                   ]
           ],
           [
            "Name" => "Mary Jane",
            "NoID" => "31332",
            "Type" => "New",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table1",
                     "rowOrder" => "0"
                   ]
           ],
           [
            "Name" => "Mary Jane",
            "NoID" => "31333",
            "Type" => "Old",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table2",
                     "rowOrder" =>"1"
                   ]
           ],

            [
            "Name" => "John Doe",
            "NoID" => "31334",
            "Type" => "Old",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table1",
                     "rowOrder"=>"0"
                   ]
           ],

           [
            "Name" => "John Doe",
            "NoID" => "31335",
            "Type" => "New",
             "attributes" =>[
                     "id"=>"Table2",
                     "rowOrder" => "1"
                   ]
           ],
 ]

     ];

$build = [];
$output = [];

$i= 0;
    foreach ($data as $value) {

            foreach ( $value as $key => $val) {

                if(!is_array($val) AND $val== "New"){

                      $build[$i][0] = $val;
                      $output = $build; 

                }else if(is_array($val) AND $val["Type"] === "New"){

                      $build[$i][$key] = "New";
                      $output = $build;


            }

            }

        $i++;   

    }

print_r(json_encode($output));



    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
foreach ($data['Table'] as $value) {
   foreach ($value as $data) {
    if(in_array('New', $data)) {
       //here you can code
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($data);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edit my code, check now. it will print array who contain Type New